# Map Key Values to Dataclass in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

how can I set properties of a dataclass by its name. For example, I have a raw HTTP GET response

```
propA=valueA
propB=valueB
```

and a data class in Kotlin

```
data class Test(var propA: String = "", var propB: String = ""){}
```

in my code i have an function that splits the response to a key value array

```
val test: Test = Test()
rawResp?.split('\n')?.forEach { item: String ->
    run {
         val keyValue = item.split('=')
         TODO
    }
}
```

In JavaScript I can do the following

```
response.split('\n').forEach(item => {
    let keyValue = item.split('=');
    this.test[keyValue[0]] = keyValue[1];
 });
```

Is there a similar way in Kotlin?

Answer (score 1):

By the question, it was not clear for me if each line represents a Test instance or not. So

If not.

```
fun parse(rawResp: String): Test = rawResp.split("\n").flatMap { it.split("=") }.let { Test(it[0], it[1]) }
```

If yes.

```
fun parse(rawResp: String): List<Test> = rawResp.split("\n").map { it.split("=") }.map { Test(it[0], it[1]) }
```

For null safe alternative you can use `nullableString.orEmpty()...`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot readily do this in Kotlin the same way you would in JavaScript (unless you are prepared to handle reflection yourself), but there is a possibility of using a Kotlin feature called [Delegated Properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html) (particularly, a use case [Storing Properties in a Map](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#storing-properties-in-a-map) of that feature).

Here is an example specific to code in your original question:

```
class Test(private val map: Map<String, String>) {
    val propA: String by map
    val propB: String by map

    override fun toString() = "${javaClass.simpleName}(propA=$propA,propB=$propB)"
}

fun main() {
    val rawResp: String? = """
        propA=valueA
        propB=valueB
        """.trimIndent()

    val props = rawResp?.split('\n')?.map { item ->
        val (key, value) = item.split('=')
        key to value
    }?.toMap() ?: emptyMap()

    val test = Test(props)

    println("Property 'propA' of test is: ${test.propA}")
    println("Or using toString: $test")
}
```

This outputs:

```
Property 'propA' of test is: valueA
Or using toString: Test(propA=valueA,propB=valueB)
```

Unfortunately, you cannot use [data classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html) with property delegation the way you would expect, so you have to 'pay the price' and define the overridden methods (`toString`, `equals`, `hashCode`) on your own if you need them.